# meaning of 'in its reality'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is 'in its reality' synonymous with 'in reality'?

Example:

> But the essence of man is no abstraction inherent in each single individual. In its reality it is the ensemble of the social relations.

Comment: That's a needlessly complex and convoluted couple of sentence—and I actually think the first one is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to "In the reality of the essence of man" (which implies that the essence of Man is *real*), so it is not the same as the idiom "in reality".

What it means is anybody's guess. It seems to me to be almost a string of complex words that fail to express any clear meaning. This sort of text seems to use complex language only to obscure, not to clarify.